# Resampling raster to even coordinates (no decimals) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, resampling

I am resampling a raster from one CRS to another, and from 0.5 m resolution to 10 m.

**But I want the new cells to have even coordinate extents, instead the old coordinate decimals remain. How do I fix this?**

[image: Coordinates and CRS of input raster (0.5 m resolution)]

I want the new raster to start at xMin 6875000.000,

[image: The desired coordinate extents]

but the new raster has 687499.521251

[image: Extent of the new resampled raster(10 m resolution)]

**How do I change so new raster has even extents?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the proper alignment I wanted in my new raster by specifying a raster with extent dividible by 10 as a Snap Raster in the "Environment Settings" under "Processing Extent".